# Sort C# ArrayList with DateTime

Tags: c#, sorting, collections, arraylist

I have a C# `ArrayList` with objects that includes following fields. I have around 10 objects in the `ArrayList`. My problem is I need to sort the `ArrayList` based on the `StartDate` available  in the system which is a DateTime variable.

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string title {get; set;}
public bool allDay { get; set; }
public string start { get; set; }
public string end { get; set; }
public string color { get; set; }
public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
public string StartDatestr { get; set; }
public string EndDatestr { get; set; }
public string StartTime { get; set; }
public string EndTime { get; set; }
public bool Alert { get; set; }
public bool Repeat { get; set; }
public Int32 RepeatDays { get; set; }
public Int32 CalendarID { get; set; }
public int CustomerNo { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
public bool IsProspect { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Can someone please enlighten me? I tried `.Sort()` but it just doesn’t do anything (its dump to try sort on `ArrayList` which has objects I know).

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

```
List<Appointment> appointments = new List<Appointment>();
```

I created the `List` as above. Now can I sort it?

Comment: Do you really need `ArrayList`(unless say you are on 1.1), can't you use `List<yourclass>` ?

Comment: I updated the question can u plz check?

Comment: `var sortedList = appointments.OrderBy(a=>a.startDate).ToList();`

Comment: i alredy answer that check my OR option in my answer you can make use of "OrderBy" to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try by creating comparere like as below

```
public class ComparerDateTime : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        MYCLASS X = x as MYCLASS;
        MYCLASS Y = y as MYCLASS;

        return X.date.CompareTo(Y.date);
    }
}

 MYCLASSList.Sort(new ComparerDateTime ());
```

**OR**

Create Generic collection than you can do this

give try to [**`Enumerable.OrderBy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) operation will do work for you..you need to include linq for this

```
IEnumerable<Pet> query = arrayList .OrderBy(x=> x.startDate );
```

if list is created like as below than try linq option

```
List<MYCLASS> arrayList  = new List<MYCLASS>();
```

Comment: That's not going to work on just `ArrayList`, which isn't generic.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan - i laredy answer that check my OR option in my answer you can make use of "OrderBy" to do it

Comment: When I try OrderBy i'm getting an error `Error 4 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Rah.BusinessEntities.Appointment>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Rah.BusinessEntities.Appointment>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: @MayuMayooresan - you need to add linq name space which is "using System.Linq;" ....

Answer (score 1):

You should try making that set of properties into a single class and then create a generic `List<NewClass>` and you can then use `IComparable` and `IComparer` to sort by a particular field.